# Trouble understanding the use of the replacement theorem in identifying infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In chapter 2 of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right the following theorem is given

> In a finite-dimensional vector space, the length of
> every linearly independent list of vectors is less than or equal to the
> length of every spanning list of vectors.

Along with the following footnote

> Suppose that for each
> positive integer $m$,
> there exists a linearly
> independent list of $m$
> vectors in $V$. Then this
> theorem implies that $V$
> is infinite dimensional.

I do not understand what exactly this result states, I have pondered this statement for hours and have looked all over the internet but I could not find an explanation. The closest I have gotten is this [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207330/infinite-dimensional-and-replacement-theorem), but the answer was more focused on the result as an implication of the replacement theorem rather than the meaning of the result itself.

All I can conclude thus far is that:
If there is an index $ m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$  such that for each value of $m$ there is a linearly independent list of the form $(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ vectors in $V$ then $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Which does not really make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about this in this way.

Suppose it is finite dimensional then say it has dimension $n$, this way we must have a set of $n$ elements which are both spanning and independent. Now let $m=n+1$, if there still exists a set of $n+1$ elements which are independent, it contradicts the theorem you had at the very beginning. Thus it is infinite dimensional.

Maybe just an example to get used to this. Consider all real polynomials, $\mathbb{R}[X]$, which you may or may not know is infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ but the footnote says it is infinite dimensional. This is because for any $m\geq 0$ you can form the set $\{1,X,\cdots, X^m\}$ which is a linearly independent set of cardinality $m+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.